# Как отдать данные пользователю на экран язык kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Использую ретрофит делаю так что сейчас при успешном получении данных я в коносоли печатаю телефон пользователя как мне передать например в таблиуц и вывести на экран?

```
api.fetchAllusers().enqueue(object : Callback<List<User>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<User>>, response: Response<List<User>>) {
                d("daniel", "onResponse: ${response.body()!![0].phone}")
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<User>>, t: Throwable) {

            }
```

Comment: а что вы хотите вывести в таблицу?

Comment: Это не обязательно таблица. Я получаю данные и их как то надо оформить списком и отдать пользователю

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

По факту если у вас не будет много данных для столбцов, то можете воспользоваться обычным списком на базе Recyclerview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

дальше в активности добавляем переменную:

```
private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
```

и в onCreate() например присваиваем значение:

```
linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
```

дальше нужно понять что именно вы хотите отобразить и сформировать разметку элемента списка, например это будет файлик с именем `recyclerview_item_row`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_animal_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Следующим этапом необходимо создать адаптер. Это класс который будет отвечать за наполнение списка данными и отрисовкой элемента:

```
class AnimalAdapter(val items : ArrayList<String>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    // Gets the number of animals in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    // Inflates the item views
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.animal_list_item, parent, false))
    }

    // Binds each animal in the ArrayList to a view
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder?.tvAnimalType?.text = items.get(position)
    }
}

class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
        val tvAnimalType = view.tv_animal_type
}
```

ну и передать данные в адаптер:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Initializing an empty ArrayList to be filled with animals
    val animals: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Loads animals into the ArrayList
        addAnimals()

        // Creates a vertical Layout Manager
        rv_animal_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        // You can use GridLayoutManager if you want multiple columns. Enter the number of columns as a parameter.
//        rv_animal_list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)

        // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
        rv_animal_list.adapter = AnimalAdapter(animals, this)

    }

    // Adds animals to the empty animals ArrayList
    fun addAnimals() {
        animals.add("dog")
        animals.add("cat")
        animals.add("owl")
        animals.add("cheetah")
        animals.add("raccoon")
        animals.add("bird")
        animals.add("snake")
        animals.add("lizard")
        animals.add("hamster")
        animals.add("bear")
        animals.add("lion")
        animals.add("tiger")
        animals.add("horse")
        animals.add("frog")
        animals.add("fish")
        animals.add("shark")
        animals.add("turtle")
        animals.add("elephant")
        animals.add("cow")
        animals.add("beaver")
        animals.add("bison")
        animals.add("porcupine")
        animals.add("rat")
        animals.add("mouse")
        animals.add("goose")
        animals.add("deer")
        animals.add("fox")
        animals.add("moose")
        animals.add("buffalo")
        animals.add("monkey")
        animals.add("penguin")
        animals.add("parrot")
    }
}
```

в вашем случае нужно вероятнее всего будет изменить разметку элемента списка. И после получения данных с сервера, в цикле заполнить какой-то массивчик. Проверяйте когда вы достигли конца массива и дальше прикрепляйте адаптер к виджету в такой же строке, но передавая свои данные:

```
recyclerView.adapter = AnimalAdapter(animals, this)
```

вот есть несколько статей по работе с таким виджетом. [1](https://android.jlelse.eu/using-recyclerview-in-android-kotlin-722991e86bf3) и [2](https://hinchman-amanda.medium.com/working-with-recyclerview-in-android-kotlin-84a62aef94ec)